# VueJs - Checbokex & Textfield based on v-model and value based on selected option

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello I'm trying to set a value when one of the options is selected. The text input will only show when an option is selected and the value from the array user.roles should populate on input text but for some reason I can't figure out why isn't working. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      roles: [{id: 1, name:'Client', value:'this is just a value'}]
    },
    roles: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Client',
        value:'',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Admin',
        value:'',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Guest',
        value:'',
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<template>

     <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="user.email" />
        </div>
        <div v-for="(role,index) in roles" :key="role.id">
            <label>{{role.name}}</label>
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="user.roles" :value="role"/>

            <p v-if="user.roles.filter(e => e.id === role.id).length > 0">
              <input type="text" value="The value from user.roles should go here.... instead of the value of role.value">
            </p>
        </div>

        <p>User's selected roels</p>
        {{user.roles}}
        </template>
</div>
```

Comment: If `filter` is used to determine existence, `find` should be used to retrieve the the value.`value="user.roles.find(e => e.id === role.id).value"`

Comment: hey @Ohgodwhy,  thanks for the suggestion and what you are proposing seems to be working however after i do that the checkbox does no longer stays checked.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Vue 2 CLI 'sandbox' app that I use for testing, so I created a single file component based on your template and Vue instance in your question.
Not sure if this will solve your problem, but I did discover a problem with initially checking the role checkboxes that the user already has.

In your example your user is already assigned role 1, but the associated checkbox was not initially being rendered as checked in my test app.  I looked at the documentation for binding multiple checkboxes to an array, as in your code, but the docs don't address the issue of initializing checkboxes bound to an array.

After searching around in vain, I noticed that in your initial 'user.roles' array, the 'Client' role object does not exactly match the 'Client' role object in data 'roles' because the property 'role.value' do not match.  When I modified your code to set the pre-assigned 'user.roles' 'Client' object 'value' property to an empty string, the checkbox for 'Client' was now correctly initially rendering as checked.

```
data() {
  return {
    user: {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      roles: [{ id: 1, name: 'Client', value: '' }]
    },
    roles: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Client',
        value: '',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Admin',
        value: '',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Guest',
        value: '',
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks I know that if I initialize the array capturing the options with { id: 1, name: 'Client', value: '' } that does work however if I enter something on value:'dssddskjdjkdkjds' checkbox is no longer selected on the initial state

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rolename: [],
    user: {
      email: 'test@test.com',
      roles: [{id: 1, name:'Client', value:'this is just a value'}]
    },
    roles: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Client',
        value:'',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Admin',
        value:'',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Guest',
        value:'',
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<template>

<div>
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="user.email" />
</div>

<div v-for="role in roles" :key="role.id">
  <label>{{ role.name }}</label>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="rolename" :value="role.name" />
</div>

<p>
  <input type="input" v-model="rolename" />
</p>

<p>User's selected roels</p>
{{ user.roles }}
        </template>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for you input on this but this is not what i'm looking for as you can see in my code. My goal is to show a input of type text so that user can enter a value and if the option is unchecked the input text field goes away. Additionally, I want to be able to show an option as selected on the initial state if there is an object already in the array keeping track of the options. Again thank you